# Why would I want to magnetize a screwdriver?

Tags: tools

Why would I want to magnetize my screwdriver?

and

How would I magnetize my screwdriver?

Comment: In my experience they magnetise themselves. You're more likely to want to *de*-magnetise them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you dont want the screw to fall off the screwdriver when you are putting a screw into a difficult place the a magnetic screwdriver is useful.I find that it works well on small screws like M3 phillips .If you are undoing a screw then the screw stays attached to the srcewdriver greatly reducing the likelyhood of loosing the screw. I magnetise my screwdrivers when needed by simply rubbing them against a strong permanent magnet .The permanent magnets are from dead loudspeakers and are normally employed as fridge magnets.

Comment: Just make sure when you rub the magnet on the screwdriver you always rub in the same direction.  If you go back and forth it won't magnetize.